# Android SDK & Eclipse Indigo bug on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am running a program of rss feed parsing with custom listview.

Now my this program works fine with android sdk eclipse Indigo on Windows 7,
but this same code is not working with my android sdk-Eclipse(Indigo) on Ubuntu system(11.04).

All other programs works perfectly fine.

Here is the error that I am getting in logcat. (**java.lang.RuntimeException** caused by **java.lang.NullPointerException**)

```
05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:44)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 05-16 14:20:24.965: E/AndroidRuntime(445):     ... 11 more
```

So what is the solution for this kind of problem,any Idea?

Thanks for listening.

Here is my code.

cusomizedlistview.java

```
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
//static final String URL = "https://news.google.com/news/feeds?ned=in&topic=n&output=rss";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }
```

Xmlparser.java

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code from your CustomizedListView? be easier to get a better idea of what might be null. Thanks

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: But it works perfect on windows7.

Comment: Please check my code.I have updated it.